# Having Difficulty to Understand Variables/Pointers on Ruby LinkedList Implementation

Tags: ruby, linked-list

I created a singly LinkedList class with ruby.
Everything went well till trying to reverse the linked list.

It does not reverse linkedlist by this method, but when I add 
    **@head.next = nil**
after **left_tmp = @head** in **reverse** method, it just works fine.

I couldn't figure out why it works when I add that, does anyone have the explanation?

BTW I am fairly new to ruby, so please don't hesitate to tell me if there are some other things that are not "**Good Practice in Ruby**".

Here is classes and relevant methods:

```
class LlNode
  attr_reader :data
  attr_accessor :next

  def initialize(val=nil)
    @data = val
    @next = nil
  end

  def to_s
    "node_data=#{@data}"
  end
end

class LinkedList
  def initialize
    @list = []
    @head = LlNode.new
  end

  def insert(val)
    n = LlNode.new val
    # List is empty
    if is_empty?
      @head = n
    else
      n.next = @head
      @head = n
    end
    self
  end

  def reverse
    return if is_empty? or @head.next.nil?

    curr = @head.next
    right_tmp = curr.next
    left_tmp = @head

    while curr != nil
      curr.next = left_tmp
      left_tmp = curr
      curr = right_tmp
      right_tmp = right_tmp.next unless right_tmp.nil?
    end
    @head = left_tmp
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're reversing a `linked list`, the first node becomes the last.  In a `singly-linked list`, the last node's `next` pointer points to `null`.  `@head`, which is initially your first node becomes the last.  That's why you add the `@head.next = nil`.

**Edit**: Simulating a dry-run to better explain the problem
Assume two nodes in the linked list: `1->2`

```
curr = @head.next  (2)
right_tmp = curr.next  (nil)
left_tmp = @head  (1)
```

First iteration of the `while` loop:

```
curr.next = left_tmp   ( 1 <-> 2)
left_tmp = curr     (2)
curr = right_tmp    (nil)
right_tmp = right_tmp.next unless right_tmp.nil?    (nil)
```

There is no second iteration since `curr == nil`

Now:

```
@head = left_tmp  (@head points to '2')
```

Final linked list state is:

```
1 <-> 2
```

Comment: you are correct, but I already change @head at the last line of the method. At the last line, left_tmp points the last  one in the linked list which has a next=nil value already.

Comment: In the last line, `left_tmp.next` is not `nil`.  Thus, the `next pointer` of the first node (in the original linked list) is not ever changed.

Comment: `left_tmp` (in the last line) points to what is originally the last node in the linked list and has now become the first node upon reversal.  It's `next` pointer no longer points to `nil`.

Comment: yeah I'm sorry I just checked and it is not nil, but for a linked list 5->4->3->2->1, left_tmp is 1 and its next is 2. Which is what it is supposed to be, right? So when I assigned @head=left_tmp, I assume everything should be fine.

Comment: I would recommend that you try doing a dry-run of the program you wrote to best understand this.

The problem is that your linked list upon reversal looks like this:
5 <-> 4 <- 3 <- 2 <- 1

Comment: The time passed between when I see your illustration and understand my mistake is 1.2 secs :) What a simple mistake, the initial root is still pointing the 2nd. Thanks a lot for your responses!

Comment: Excellent - I also edited the answer to explain this better.  Hope its helpful.